# SortedList ADT / Array Based Implementation

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures

I am having some trouble working out the bugs on this program. I continue to get "unknown Type name" errors and I haven't the slightest idea how to solve them. Does anyone have any ideas?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Just for reference (and so I don't have to say it again in the comments) the program purpose is as follows:

**Function:** Merge two sorted lists into a third sorted list.

**Preconditions:** list1 and list2 have been initialized and are sorted by key using function ComparedTo. List1 and list2 do not have any keys in common.

**Postconditions:** result is a sorted list that contains all of the items from list1 and 
list2.

```
#include <iostream>

void MergeLists(SortedType list1, SortedType list2, SortedType& result)
{
int length1;
int length2;
int counter1 = 1;
int counter2 = 1;

ItemType item1;
itemType item2;

length1 = list1.lengthIs();
length2 = list2.lengthIs();
list1.ResetList();
list2.ResetList();
list1.GetNextItem(item1);
list1.GetNextItem(item2);
result.MakeEmpty();

while( counter1 <= length1 && counter2 <= length2)
Switch( item1.comparedTo(item2))

{
    Case LESS:  result.InsertItem(item1);
    If( counter1 < length1)
    List1.GetNextItem(item1);
    Counter1++;
    break;
    Case GREATER:  result.InsertItem(item2);
    If( counter2 < length2)
    List2.GetNextItem(item2);
    Counter2++;
    break;
}
For( counter1 <== length1; counter1++)
{
    Result InsertItem(item1);
    If( counter1 < length1)
    List.GetNextItem(item1);
}
For( counter2 <== length2; counter2++)
{
    Result.InsertItem(item2);
    If(counter2 < length2)
    List2.GetNextItem(item2);
}
}
```

Comment: Either this isn't c++ or you really need a c++ [tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/)

Comment: c++ is case-significant: `Switch` should be `switch`, `If` should be `if`, etc.

Comment: tag the language which you want to work out this code.